# Select background with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple HTML5/CSS3/JS website which involves changing the theme (background) with a dropdown menu. However, my code does nothing.

```
             <div id="theme-picker">
        <form action="">
        <select name="themakeuze" id="thema" onchange="changeTheme();">
        <option value="dark" >Donker thema</option>
        <option value="light">Licht thema</option>
        </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function changeTheme()
        {
            var e = document.getElementById("thema");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            if (strUser == "Donker thema")
            {
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/binding_dark.png)';
            }
            if (strUser == "Licht thema")
            {
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/binding_light.png)';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I'm obviously not very good at JavaScript. We're not allowed any libraries.

Comment: Spelling mistake in 'document.getElementById("thema");'. Check please. 'thema' should be 'theme'

Comment: the form id is also "thema". It's a dutch word, not a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The `onchange` event should be applied to the `select` itself:

```
<select name="thema" id="thema" onchange="changeTheme();">
<option value="dark">Donker thema</option>
<option value="light">Licht thema</option>
</select>
```

(2) The following lines should be placed inside the function `changeTheme()` rather than outside it:

```
var e = document.getElementById("thema");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

(3) The `if` statement should be properly written as:

```
if (strUser == "dark")
```

Comment: Ahh yes, that makes more sense already, though it still doesn't work. I've updated the code in the original post.

Comment: @user2820952
You have a conflicting name / id in the `select`.. Change the name to something like `Mythema` or something else... It should work fine then..

Answer (score 0):

change the code and set onchange="changeTheme()" on the Select not in the option

Answer (score 0):

Also prepend "document" where you try to set the background.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/binding_dark.png)';
```